# How to show the client's IP address in server side in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.NET with .NET Framework 2.0.

I created one chat application.

#### Server code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim handler As Socket
    Public th As Thread
    Public th1 As Thread
    Public Data As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Public msg As Byte()

    Delegate Sub SetDisplay(ByVal [Text] As String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.listner = New System.Net.Sockets.Socket(Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Text = "Server Started"
        Connect()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Connect()
        Try
            ipHostinfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName())
            ipAdd = ipHostinfo.AddressList(0)
            localEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 11000) ' ip + port
            listner.Bind(localEndPoint)
            listner.Listen(10)
            th = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Acceptstart)
            th.Start()
            i = 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Acceptstart() 'Accept the client's request
        handler = listner.Accept()
        th1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Receive)
        th1.Start()
        i = 2
    End Sub

    ' ---'Transfer button ' sending message ----
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Txtmsg.Text) 'getting msg from textbox
            handler.Send(msg)
            Txtmsg.Text = ""  'deleting msg from textbox after sending
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub


    Public Sub Receive() ' to receive msg
        Try
            Dim bytes(100000) As Byte
            Dim bytesRec As Integer
            bytes = New Byte(100000) {}

A:          While True ' Always receiving msg
                bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes) 'bytesRec is a variable to store received msg (ACK)
                If bytesRec &gt; 0 Then 'if any msg (ACK) received the it is &gt;0
                    Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec) ' storing received ACK in Data
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While


C:          Proccessdata(Data) ' to display received msg (ACK) in Listbox

            GoTo A
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Server Problem:" + ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub Proccessdata(ByVal str As String) 'to display the received msg (ACK) in Listbox (ACK)
        If Me.List.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetDisplay(AddressOf Proccessdata)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {str})
        Else
            Me.List.Items.Add(str) 'displaying ACK string in Listbox

        End If
    End Sub

    '' form close ' Close socket connection ----
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        If i = 1 Then
            th.Abort()
        End If
        If i = 2 Then
            th.Abort()
            th1.Abort()
        End If
        If handler IsNot Nothing Then
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both) 'while exiting or closing then release the socket
            handler.Close()
        End If
        Dim p1 As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
        p1.Kill()
    End Sub
End Class
```

#### Client code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text.Encoder

Public Class Conn
    Public msg As Byte()
    Public th As Thread
    Public Data As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Delegate Sub SetDisplay(ByVal [Text] As String)

    Private Sub Conn_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.sender = New System.Net.Sockets.Socket(Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)
    End Sub

    '--------Connect button --------
    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Connect()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Connect()
        Try
            ipHostinfo = Dns.Resolve(Txtserver.Text) ' Server ip from textbox
            ipAdd = ipHostinfo.AddressList(0)
            remoteEP = New IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 11000) ' ip + port
            sender.Connect(remoteEP)
            th = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Receive)
            th.Start()
            i = 1
            Button1.Text = "Connected"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    '--------------------Send ACK button----------------
    Public Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Txtmsg.Text) 'sending ACK from textbox
            Me.sender.Send(msg)
            Txtmsg.Text = "" ' deleting from textbox
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Receive() ' to receive msg
        Dim bytes(100000) As Byte
        Dim bytesRec As Integer
A:      While True ' Always receiving msg
            bytes = New Byte(100000) {}
            bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes) 'bytesRec is a integer variable to store received msg number of bytes as integer
            If bytesRec &gt; 0 Then 'if any msg (ACK) received the it is &gt;0
                Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec)
                Exit While
            End If
        End While

        Proccessdata(Data) ' to display received msg  in Listbox

        GoTo A
    End Sub

    Public Sub Proccessdata(ByVal str As String) ' received msg from server
        If Me.List.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetDisplay(AddressOf Proccessdata)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {str})
        Else
            Me.List.Items.Add(str) 'displaying received msg string in Listbox
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Conn_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        If i = 1 Then
            th.Abort()
            Me.sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
            Me.sender.Close()
        End If
        Dim p1 As Process
        Dim p As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("client.exe")
        For Each p1 In p
            p1.Kill()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to see the client's IP address on the server side.

I would like to be able to show from which server the client is on server-side.

For example:

> Server got a connection from IP address 10.10.63.75 port 35689

If it is possible I want to show the client's machine's name...

Example:

> - Dipankar-PC Windows 8

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AcceptStart`, `handler` is of the `Socket` type and that contains what you need. You can do

```
Dim ip As IPEndPoint = handler.RemoteEndPoint
TextMsg.Text = TextMsg.Text + ip.Address + "on port " + ip.Port + Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: `Dim ip As IPEndPoint = handler.RemoteEndPoint
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + ip.Address.ToString() + "on port " + ip.Port.ToString() + Environment.NewLine`      it's working fine ... thank you so much

Comment: is it possible to show the client's Computer Name ? for example- my computer name is Dipankar-PC  is it possible to show in server side ?

Comment: If your computer's name is registered in your network's DNS you could get it by something like `Dim host as IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.99.201")`.